# Print content of scroll x and y direction div

Tags: jquery, css

**My problem is that,**

- I want  to print content inside of
  scroll in horizontal and Vertical direction

[image]

```
<button class="printtable">Print</button>
<div id="applicationtableDiv">
<table>
<!-- table content -->
</table>
</div>
 <script type="text/ecmascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/print.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.printtable', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('#applicationtableDiv>table').print();
              });
});
</script>
```

I'm using this plugin 
[click here](https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print)

This plugin is working for me but i want to print content inside of scroll x and y

Print Out of records
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a scrollbars for your table just wrap it inside `div` with `overflow:auto` style:

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
     <!-- your table goes here -->
</div>
```

That's all.

Comment: Dan Spirit I don't want to create scrollbars . i want to print content inside of scroll.